# Cannot install Django 1.9.6 on python anywhere

Tags: pythonanywhere

I am trying to install this Django version on python anywhere but i get this error :

```
Looking in links: /usr/share/pip-wheels
Collecting Django==1.9.6
Using cached  
   
https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cb/97/081df31f2a3850988b92ad4464e95f9e4b257aa5a34e120bca89c260de96/Django-1.9.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl
ERROR: django-mptt 0.10.0 has requirement Django>=1.11, but you'll have django 1.9.6 which is incompatible.
ERROR: django-contrib-comments 1.9.1 has requirement Django>=1.11, but you'll have django 1.9.6 which is incompatible.
ERROR: django-classy-tags 0.9.0 has requirement Django>=1.11, but you'll have django 1.9.6 which is incompatible.
ERROR: django-sekizai 1.0.0 has requirement django>=1.11, but you'll have django 1.9.6 which is incompatible.
Installing collected packages: Django
  Found existing installation: Django 2.2.7
    Uninstalling Django-2.2.7:
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/bin/__pycache__/django-admin.cpython-35.pyc'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

I also want to migrate all our installed python 3.5 libraries on python3.5 folder lib on python anywhere so that our websites can use . I do not need to reinstall this libraries if that is the case then i do not think we need to use python anywhere for our 20+ Django websites migration.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is suggested at the end of the error message: `Consider using the --user option or check the permissions.` Just go with `--user` option while installing with `pip` (remember to specify which Python version should be used by pip, otherwise it will default to 2.7) and it should work fine. You might want to read [this PythonAnywhere help page](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/InstallingNewModules/) as well.